# Login to a website while using libcurl and C++

Tags: c++, authentication, web, libcurl

I'm new to stackoverflow so please don't break me up if there was any questions regarding this.

So I want to login to a website by using libcurl, this is the code fragment I got from the website (regarding the 2 input boxes needed):

```
<input type="text" name="vb_login_username" id="navbar_username" size="15" accesskey="u"             tabindex="96" value="Username" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Username') this.value = '';">
<input type="password" name="vb_login_password" id="navbar_password" size="15" tabindex="97">
```

How should I implement these? I tried with the following code fragment but I'm not sure if this works since I receive no answer from the lib, however. (only necessary code included)

```
data="vb_login_username=test&vb_login_password=test";
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.somesite.com/login");
curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
res[0] = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );
```

Comment: Have you tried following [this page](https://www.hackthissite.org/articles/read/1078), section: "Retrieving a webpage (With cookies!)"